# React-native animation: Trying to combine multiple animations; getting error

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

I am trying to do an animation where I start with a colored square in the top left corner. Clicking it should move the square to the center of the screen while scaling it to twice its size. Then it should flip over and show a back side. When I try to load the app on the emulator I get this error:

[image]

This is the code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import
    {
        StyleSheet,
        View,
        Text,
        Animated,
        Dimensions,
        TouchableWithoutFeedback
    }
from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        animation: new Animated.ValueXY(),
        scaleAnimation: new Animated.Value(1),
        rotateAnimation: new Animated.Value(0)
    };

    startAnimation = () => {
        const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window");
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.timing(this.state.animation.y, {
                toValue: (height / 2) - (this._height / 2),
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.animation.x, {
                toValue: (width / 2) - (this._width / 2),
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.scaleAnimation, {
                toValue: 2,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: true
            })
        ]).start(() => {
            Animated.timing(this.state.rotateAnimation, {
                toValue: 180,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: true
            }).start();
        })
    }

    saveDimensions = (e) => {
        this._width = e.nativeEvent.layout.width;
        this._height = e.nativeEvent.layout.height;
    }

    render() {
        const animatedStyles = {
            transform: [
                {
                    translateX: this.state.animation.x
                },
                {
                    translateY: this.state.animation.y
                },
                {
                    scale: this.state.scaleAnimation
                }
            ]
        }

        const frontInterpolate = this.state.rotateAnimation.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 180],
            outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg']
        })

        const backInterpolate = this.state.rotateAnimation.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 180],
            outputRange: ['180deg', '360deg']
        })

        const frontAnimatedStyle = {
            transform: [
                {
                    rotateY: this.frontInterpolate
                }
            ]
        }

        const backAnimatedStyle = {
            transform: [
                {
                    rotateY: this.backInterpolate
                }
            ]
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                    onPress={() => this.startAnimation()}
                    onLayout={() => this.saveDimensions()}
                >
                    <View>
                        <Animated.View
                            style={[styles.box, animatedStyles, frontAnimatedStyle]}
                        >
                            <Text>Front</Text>
                        </Animated.View>
                        <Animated.View
                            style={[backAnimatedStyle, styles.box, styles.boxBack]}
                        >
                            <Text>Back</Text>
                        </Animated.View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        //alignItems: 'center',
        //justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    box: {
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        backgroundColor: 'tomato',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
    },
    boxBack: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
});
```

I don't even know if the animation will work since it won't even load without getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the snack https://snack.expo.io/@ziyoshams/frisky-watermelon, and try to examine the code. Your error was coming from `onLayout`, but modified a lot. Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  Animated,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    animation: new Animated.ValueXY(),
    scaleAnimation: new Animated.Value(1),
    box1RotateAnimation: new Animated.Value(0),
    box2RotateAnimation: new Animated.Value(0),
  };

  startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.state.animation.y, {
        toValue: height / 2 - this._height / 2,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.animation.x, {
        toValue: width / 2 - this._width / 2,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.scaleAnimation, {
        toValue: 2,
        duration: 500,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }),
    ]).start(() => {
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(this.state.box1RotateAnimation, {
          toValue: 180,
          duration: 500,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
        Animated.timing(this.state.box2RotateAnimation, {
          toValue: 180,
          duration: 500,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
      ]).start();
    });
  };

  saveDimensions = e => {
    this._width = e.nativeEvent.layout.width;
    this._height = e.nativeEvent.layout.height;
  };

  render() {
    const frontInterpolate = this.state.box1RotateAnimation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 180],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '90deg'],
    });

    const backInterpolate = this.state.box2RotateAnimation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 180],
      outputRange: ['90deg', '0deg'],
    });

    const parentAnimation = {
      transform: [
        {
          translateX: this.state.animation.x,
          translateY: this.state.animation.y,
          scale: this.state.scaleAnimation,
        },
      ],
    };

    const box1Animation = {
      transform: [
        {
          rotateY: frontInterpolate,
        },
      ],
    };

    const box2Animation = {
      transform: [
        {
          rotateY: backInterpolate,
        },
      ],
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={this.startAnimation}
          onLayout={this.saveDimensions}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.box, parentAnimation]}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.box1, box1Animation]}>
              <Text>Front</Text>
            </Animated.View>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.box2, box2Animation]}>
              <Text>Back</Text>
            </Animated.View>
          </Animated.View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  box: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
  box1: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: 'tomato',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
  box2: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: This works. I just had to put each transform item in the parentAnimation in its own set of { }. The only thing I don't like now is that it rotates 90 degrees, then rotates 90 degrees back the same way to reveal the back side. I'm trying to figure out how to make it do one continuous 180 rotation going the same direction the whole time and reveal the back side.

Comment: I'm not sure what the proper protocol is here. This technically answered the question, which was how to get rid of the error message. So should I go ahead and mark this as the answer and then create a new question about the flip animation?

Comment: You know, we all solve the same problem in different ways. Based on the description you provided, i thought i could solve it with 90deg. But, you can achieve your 180deg by playing with the zIndex of 2 boxes. Good luck.